# Can javascript actions be made to change the document's activeElement as would happen with real user interactions?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm playing with the writing of an implementation of the [JSONWire Protocol](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol).
The implementation simulates user behaviour (click, navigate, etc.)... my goal is to make a lighter (albeit less feature complete) version of th selenium server.

Now I've noticed that when simulating events (for instance, a click), the `document.activeElement` property does not change.

I've made this JSfiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/75bq50wa/6/.

You should notice that if you click the "Click me" checkbox, the `activeElement` changes, whereas it does NOT change when clicking using Javascript.

My interpretation is that only native events alter the state of the `activeElement` property.

Is this correct, or is there a way to better emulate user events in Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The W3C Recommendation (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html) says:

```
document . activeElement

    Returns the currently focused element.
```

This means, you need to additionally focus() the element, in order to correctly simulate a User's click.

See this updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e3vg5k75/